# React: Conditionally required CSS file always included in build

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

For testing purposes I include a CSS file that disables animation for certain CSS class, this is used so that [differencify](https://github.com/NimaSoroush/differencify) tests do not produce spurious diffs. This CSS file is only included if certain environmental variables are set:

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL === 'localhost') {
  // Use a fixed clock against local backend
  moment.now = () => 1558396800000;

  // Disable animations when running localcd to avoid diff on visual tests
  if (process.env.REACT_APP_DISABLE_ANIMATIONS === 'true') {
    require('./disable-animations.css');
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This works perfectly when running locally, the animations are disabled when backend is `localhost` and enabled when running against other backends. But for some reason the animations are also disabled in the deployed code that is built using `react-scripts build`. `moment.now()` is *not* overriden in the built code, so it seems that `react-scripts build` will include all resources passed to `require()` regardless of their conditionality? Is there a way to avoid that? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This seems odd `process.env.REACT_APP_DISABLE_ANIMATIONS !== 'true'` you're checking that the disable flag is false (so, enabled), then disabling animations by including the stylesheet. I don't know if this is the issue, but it seems logically wrong.

Comment: `process.env.REACT_APP_DISABLE_ANIMATIONS` is dynamic, so the build will always include it.  Some environment variables in say webpack will evaluate during build, eg. `NODE_ENV`..  If you wish to make this a compile option, have a look at -> https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/  Assuming of course your using webpack, I assume rollup etc will have something similar.

Comment: @DBS You're right, the original environmental variable was named something else but I edited it for this post so it made more sense, but in doing so changed the semantic. Will edit the post to reflect the correct semantic.

Comment: @Keith This should never be true in production, so I want the build to ignore it always.

Comment: @Limon  What's never true in production, don't understand your comment.  Like I pointed out if you want `REACT_APP_DISABLE_ANIMATIONS` to be a compile option,  and if your say using webpack use the define plugin, that's what's is designed for.

Comment: Thanks @Keith, I solved it by adding additional condition on `NODE_ENV`, if you want to submit a solution I'll mark that as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_DISABLE_ANIMATIONS === 'true') {
  require('./disable-animations.css');
}
```

In the above if condition, the evaluation is dynamic, the compiler does not know this is a compile time directive, it will only know to evaluate at runtime.

If using webpack there is a way to tell the compiler this is a build time constant, an example of that is the `process.env.NODE_ENV`, with this the compiler will evaluate this value at build time and not runtime.   It does this by replacing what's in NODE_ENV with it's value, so for example.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('./disable-animations.css');
}
```

During production the above will actually get converted to ->

```
if ('production' !== 'production') {
  require('./disable-animations.css');
}
```

As such the `require('./disable-animations.css');` will be excluded from build.

If you have more complicated build time constants you want to use, there is also the https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/ , with this you can have even finer control than just development & production, eg. you might want a production build with logging enabled, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All `require()` will add static files in the final build, whether they are there on true or false conditions. I would say that the workaround could be such that you use `StyleSheet.create()` instead and make CSS dynamic in there. You should be able to control any CSS property logically, and even output an empty StyleSheet object in the end, thus not including anything unrelated in the build.

From https://facebook.github.io:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  activeTitle: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```

In your case it could look like this:

```
const isIncluded = true;
const styles = isIncluded ? StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  activeTitle: {
    color: 'red',
  },
}) : null;
```

EDIT: While for the majority of cases this will be true, as @Keith has pointed out, "...that's not strictly true, eg.. if you did if (false) { require("something"); } the compiler will know this is dead code an will exclude it...". In other words, in the cases where compiler will be sure that this code will never be reached, `require()` will not be included in the build

Comment: `All require() will add static files in the final build,`  That's not strictly true,  eg.. if you did `if (false) { require("something"); }`  the compiler will know this is dead code an will exclude it,.  And say in webpack using the define plugin is exactly how this works for doing different compiled versions.

Comment: I guess you're right. Only the cases where compiler absolutely knows this will always be false, it will ignore the require.